# second instance of vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Does anyone know how to open a second instance of VS2012?  I would like to have ome solution open and then open another to compare code.  Used to be able to do this with VS2010.  Or am I just missing something here?

Comment: Apparently this is now a 'feature' of Windows 8

Comment: If your questions has been answered, I would apreciate if you accept the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can not start more than 1 VS2012 instances at once using the metro interface! IMHO this is stupid, took a while to figure it out too.

Anyways, start a second instance (after having opened 1 instace) by doing:
Right-Click on the VS2012 icon in the taskbar and choose "Visual Studio 2012" or 
Hold Left-Click + drag upwards and choose "Visual Studio 2012" or 
Just use the desktop icon if you have it.

Comment: Alternatives to "hold left-click + drag upwards and choose Visual Studio 2012": 2) right click on the same icon and choose Visual Studio 2012, 3) middle click the icon, 4) shift + left click the icon.

Comment: Another possibility to open a solution in a new VS instance: Double Klick the *.sln file in Explorer (default location: documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\*)

Answer (score 1):

You can hold down Shift key and click on any program already running on desktop taksbar to open a new instance. Works for any version of VS also.

Comment: Nice to know. Works well

Answer (score 0):

Just start vs2012 twice, and open different projects. I do this quite often.

Note: Open visual studio before loading the project. If you start it once, load a project, and from that window you open another project, your first project will close...

Comment: Does it make a difference that I am using Windows 8??

Comment: in the metro interface it probably does, but in the win7 interface it shouldn't. but I am not sure as I'm using win 7.

Comment: the problem is i can only see the icon to launch in the metro interface.  is there another way?

Comment: can you navigate to the install location from the win 7 interface, and launch it there twice? BTW: does visual studio launch in the Metro interface or in the win 7 interface?

Comment: it launches in the win 7 interface, i'll try to use explorer later to launch another instance.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows 8, you should right click the VS2012 icon on your task bar if you have one instance open already. 
Then click "VS 2012" link from the dropdown list.

:)Good Luck mate.

Answer (score 0):

You can just right-click on VS icon and choose "Open new Window".

It works fine for me (VS 2013, Win 8.1).

http://screencast.com/t/xK1EMEmHoBW